# Average Ignoring Blank Columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Really struggling with formula on a calculated column on my SharePoint list for some reason!

I am trying to get the average of 3 columns sometimes one will be blank some times there will be no blanks.

Here is the formula I have:

```
=IF(COUNT([Column1],[Column2],[Column3])="","",SUM([Column1],[Column2],[Column3])/COUNT([Column1],[Column2],[Column3]))
```

On this test Column 2 is empty and this returns #DIV/0!

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: All 3 columns are "Number" columns? can you add the screenshot of list view (for sample data to test) to your question if possible?

Comment: Hey, @GaneshSanap, Yes number columns, apologies, its a simple scoring system of 1,2 or 3. on some occasions it will be blank though.

Comment: Try my answer given below. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all 3 columns are of type "Number", use below formula:

```
=IF(COUNT([Column1],[Column2],[Column3])=0,0,SUM([Column1],[Column2],[Column3])/COUNT([Column1],[Column2],[Column3]))
```

I just tried it & it works for me:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)

Comment: Thank you very much, I am however still getting a zero in average. I will list some more detail below.

Column one and Column Three a choice of 1,2,3
Column two is a calculated column which has divided by two a choice column of 1,2,3,4,5,6 that gives an answer of 1,2 or 3

When Column Two is blank on mine I get 0 as the average using your formula

Comment: I have changed choice to Number and fixed it all Thank you very much @ganeshSanap

Comment: When you use the choice columns, retuned value of column will be **text** and not number. In such cases, use [VALUE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/value-function-1fc46e51-4a25-4ba0-bce2-512dd5d4d872) like: `VALUE([Column1])` and `VALUE([Column2])`. But it's always better to use the Number columns for calculations.